# Cоздание формы в Laravel через класс Form

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Создал форму в Laravel, но не знаю как добавить класс Form  в проект

```
  {{Form::open()}}
                <input type="checkbox" name="task" id="task_{{$task->id}}"
                {{$task->status ? 'checked' : ''}} onclick="this.form.submit()" />
                <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{$task->id}}"
                <label for="task_{{$task->id}}">{{$task->content}}</label>
                <a href = "delete/{{$task->id}}">Х</a>
            {{Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт о стилях и прочих параметрах которые должны добавиться в тег `<form>`, то все данные которые нужно передать в форму указываются первым параметром:

```
Form::open(['route' => ['post.update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT', 'name' => 'formEdit', 'class' => 'my-best-form'])
```